# Find the limit of this sequence.(sequence of the functions)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, uniform-convergence

Let the sequence of the continuous functions, $f_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f_n(x) \geq 0$ on $[0,1]$

The $f_n$ has the below properties.

(1) $\int_0^1 f_n(x) dx = 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

(2) $f_n(x)$ is  pointwise convergent to $0$ for $\forall x \in [0,1]$

(3) $\forall r \in \mathbb{R} s.t. 0 \lt r \lt 1, f_n(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $[r,1]$

Say the $g(x) = f_n(x)e^{-x}$, What is $lim_{n \to \infty} $$\int_{0}^{1}g(x)dx$ ?

---

My attempt)
By property (3)

$lim_{n \to \infty}$  $\int_0^1g(x)dx$ = $lim_{n \to \infty}$ (  $\int_0^rg(x)dx$  +   $\int_r^1g(x)dx$ ) = $lim_{n \to \infty}$   $\int_0^rg(x)dx$

Then by M.V.T. for the integral

$\exists c s.t. 0 \lt c \lt r \lt 1$, $lim_{n \to \infty}$   $e^{-c} \int_0^r f_n(x)dx$

As $r \to 0$, clearly $c \to 0$

Hence the limit is $0$

But the answer was $1$.

I can't figure out which point do I have a mistake. Plus in my answer sheet, There are no method finding the value of the limit is $1$. Still I don't know why the value is $1$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How did you conclude that the limit is $0$?

Comment: Since $e^{-c}$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^r f_n(x)dx$ goes to $0 $ As $r \to 0$. Hence $e^{-c}$$\int_0^r f_n(x)dx$ goes to $0$

Comment: You cannot conclude that $\int_0^{r} f_n(x)dx \to 0$ just becasue $f_n(x) \to 0$ for each $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not prove that the limit is $0$. Here is a valid argument:

Consider $\int_0^{1} [1-e^{-x}] f_n(x)dx$. Using the inequality $1-e^{-x} \leq x$ we see that $$\int_0^{r} [1-e^{-x}] f_n(x)dx \leq \int_0^{r} xf_n(x)dx \leq r \int_0^{r} f_n(x)dx \leq r.$$ Also $\int_r^{1} [1-e^{-x}] f_n(x)dx \to 0$ by uniform convergence. Conclude that $\int_0^{1} [1-e^{-x}] f_n(x)dx \to 0$ which is equivalent to the statement $\int_0^{1}  g_n(x)dx \to 1$.

Comment: Oh.. According to your perfect proof, the limit value should be "$1$". But How could I find the value "$1$"? Since the proving itself, Just justifying the Value is "$1$" under the conclusion that value is "1 " Not showing process finding the value. (I.e. Only I can show is justifying the result, can't finding process the value "1")

Comment: One way is to take some examples. I suggest looking at $f_n(x)=n(\frac 1n-x)$ for $x <\frac  1n$ and $0$ for $x \geq \frac 1 n$  as  an example in which  the hypothesis is satisfied and you can find the limit by direct calculation of the integral. @se-hyuckyang

Comment: @se-hyuckyang For guessing what the limit should be you can forget about the continuity assupmtion and consider the function $f_n$ which has the value $n$ when $x <\frac 1 n$ and $0$ for all other $x$. In this case $\int g_n(x)dx=n(1-e^{-\frac 1n})$ and the limit of this sequence is $1$.